# Uncheck all CheckBoxes using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, checkbox

I have three checkboxes and after selection an entry can be made in the listbox (see below). How can I remove the entry from the listbox again when i want to change the state of the checkbox (unchecked)? Many thanks in advance for all your help!

```
private CheckBox[] checkboxes;
private string[] cbx;

checkboxes = new[] {checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3};

checkBox1.Tag =  "string1"; 
checkBox2.Tag =  "string2";
checkBox3.Tag =  "string3"; 

foreach (var checky in checkboxes)
{
   checky.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;
}

private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   cbx = checkboxes.Where(checky => checky.Checked)
  .Select(checky => checky.Tag)
  .Cast<string>()
  .ToArray();

  listBox4.Items.AddRange(cbx);

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to remove everything in the list box, before you add the checked items to the list box:

```
private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cbx = checkboxes.Where(checky => checky.Checked)
        .Select(checky => checky.Tag)
        .Cast<string>()
        .ToArray();

    listBox4.Items.Clear(); // here!
    listBox4.Items.AddRange(cbx);
}
```

Any time any of the check boxes get checked, you remove everything in the list box, whether or not they are checked. Then you get the currently checked items and add them to the list box.